# Determinant of elliptic curve torsion subgroup

Tags: elliptic-curves

In Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves page 93, he defines
$$\det:E[m]\to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}, \quad \det(aT_1+bT_2,cT_1+dT_2)=ad-bc$$
where $\{T_1,T_2\}$ is a basis for $E[m]$.

I don't get why elements in $E[m]$ are of the form $(aT_1+bT_2,cT_1+dT_2)$ and not just $aT_1+bT_2$.

Comment: I think there's a typo in the book, since it's obviously should be $det: E[m] \times E[m] \to  \frac{Z}{mZ}$

Comment: Right, thank you.